# How can I specify each iteration in a for loop's output? Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a .json file with multiple values, seperated by commas. I would like to go through the file and output each value sequentially, as variables. The first one being x1, the second one being x2 and so on. The point is so that I can use these values in an equation later on.
The output would look like this:

```
x1 = 0.0234
x2 = 0.512
x3 = 0.9782
```

I pretty sure I need to use a for loop after this:

```
g = open('beat_times_knownsong1.json')
another_song = json.load(g)
```

EDIT: this is some of the .json data:

```
0.023219954648526078,
    0.5108390022675737,
    0.9752380952380952,
    1.4628571428571429,
    1.9504761904761905,
    2.414875283446712,
    2.9024943310657596,
    3.3668934240362813,
    3.8545124716553287,
    4.31891156462585,
    4.806530612244898,
    5.270929705215419,
    5.758548752834467,
    6.222947845804988,
    6.710566893424036,
    7.174965986394557,
```

they're just numbers increasing in value. If I just do:

```
g = open('beat_times_knownsong1.json')
another_song = json.load(g)

for beat in another_song:
    print(beat)
```

then it just prints the values. I would like for it to save each value to an "x" variable, increasing from x1 = 0.023219954648526078 to x2, x3 and so on.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Do you want to know how to open and iterate over a list in the form of a JSON file ? can you edit your question with a sample of the JSON data & some code that you've tried?

Comment: @CodeRedacted Thank you for the reply, I've edited my post. All I want is to assign each value of the .json file to increasing variables. So x1, x2, x3 and so on

Comment: Why? You already appear to have a list you can index. You *could* write something like `x1, x2, x3 =  some_list` if you know exactly how many items were in the list, but why bother? Just use `some_list[0]`, `some_list[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`enumerate`](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) to get the index of the current value in the list you are iterating over.
2. There are different ways in Python to convert a string to a variable (see e.g. [here](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-string-to-variable-name/)). One is using the `locals` method, which returns a `dict` that reflects all local variables defined in a scope (e.g. a function) and allows manipulating them (e.g. reassigning, adding new variables or deleting existing ones).

Example:

```py
g = open('beat_times_knownsong1.json')
another_song = json.load(g)

for i, beat in enumerate(another_song):
    locals()[f"x{i}"] = beat

print(x0)
print(x1)
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this is the best option for me

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a dictionary instead of variable:

```
g = open('beat_times_knownsong1.json')
another_song = json.load(g)
variable_dict={}
i=0
for beat in another_song:
    variable_dict["x"+str(i)]=beat
    i+=1
```

and you can get the value you want like this:

> variable_dict["x1"]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I print(variable_dict) here, I get this output:

{'x+str(i)': 0.023219954648526078}
{'x+str(i)': 0.5108390022675737}
{'x+str(i)': 0.9752380952380952}
{'x+str(i)': 1.4628571428571429}
{'x+str(i)': 1.9504761904761905}
{'x+str(i)': 2.414875283446712}
{'x+str(i)': 2.9024943310657596}
{'x+str(i)': 3.3668934240362813}
{'x+str(i)': 3.8545124716553287}
{'x+str(i)': 4.31891156462585}
{'x+str(i)': 4.806530612244898}
{'x+str(i)': 5.270929705215419}

Am I printing the wrong thing?

Comment: sorry my bad i just edit response